# How index mongodb collection on embedded properties?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Example of data structure:

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "num_results": 1,
        "total_results": 500,
        "results_remaining": 499,
        "matches": [
            {
                "match_id": 792680045,
                "match_seq_num": 712015697,
                "start_time": 1406113521,
                "lobby_type": 8,
                "radiant_team_id": 0,
                "dire_team_id": 0,
                "players": [
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 0,
                        "hero_id": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 137113820,
                        "player_slot": 128,
                        "hero_id": 11
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]

    }
}
```

That's small part of data (in original will be 100 matches in list and 10 players in every match.) - and income value of data - is 10 millions matches per month.

That's dota2 game matches history. I want two fast types of search:

1. Search by match params (match_id, start_time and lobby_type)
2. Search matches by player_id from embedded players data

How should I organize it in Mongodb?

Comment: I'm trying to understand something from your question apart from it actually seems to be asking multiple questions ( quite too broad ) and that you seem to not have much knowledge of MongoDB even though you somehow appear to be working on a lucrative contract. We should help you get paid why?

Comment: Could you answer the question?

Comment: Which one? This is too broad. Please make it one succinct question.

Comment: I removed the second question (how powerful the database server needs to be), because it's the one which is less on-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database schema seems to be fine to satisfy the two queries you mentioned. Just create the following indexes and you should be fine:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "result.matches.match_id" : 1 });
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "result.matches.start_time" : 1 });
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "result.matches.lobby_type" : 1 });
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "result.matches.players.account_id" : 1 });
```

When you not just need the account_id for the mentioned use-cases but also some more information about the players (like their name), you should duplicate that information in the player-subdocument so you don't need a subsequent query to your collection of players.

But I have a concern which might affect your write performance: MongoDB doesn't like documents which grow over time. MongoDB always tries to keep each document in a consecutive section of the database file to improve read performance. But that means that when a document update increases the document size, the document needs to be moved to the end of the file which is an expensive operation. That means when your document starts with one match and then recieves more and more each day, your update performance could suffer. As a tradeoff you could create a separate collection for matches.

Comment: Yes, you are right about collection of matches, now I save data the same way in relational scheme. I have table matches and table players_in_matches. About mongo I said wrong about saving data - really I need Matches collection, and I will insert new matches at the end, after each obtaining part of data, as I showed at question.